# No exact matches in call to instance method 'buttonStyle'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am still very new to programming and please excuse my beginner mistakes.

I've already looked for the problem, but I can't get any further on my own. Maybe one of you can help me, as I don't think the problem is really that big. When I use this code, this error

No exact matches in call to instance method 'buttonStyle'

Inheritance from non-protocol type 'ButtonStyle'

Cannot find type 'Configuration' in scope

message keeps appearing.

What do I have to do to stop getting these?

Best regards

```
import SwiftUI

struct ButtonStyleGuide: View {
var body: some View {
VStack (spacing:30) {
Text("Button Styles")

            Button { } label: {
                Text("small primary button style")
                
            }
            .buttonStyle(SmallButtonStyle)
            
            Button { } label: {
                Text("small primary button - disabled")
            }
            .buttonStyle(SmallButtonStyle())
            .disabled(true)
            
        }
    }

}

struct SmallButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
@Environment(.isEnabled) var isEnabled

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .buttonStyle()
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .background(Capsule().fill(Color("purple-500")))
            .padding(12.5)
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.8 : 1)
    }

}

struct ButtonStyleGuide_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
ButtonStyleGuide()
}
}
```

I have done a YouTube Tutorial and get stuc at this point.

Comment: Hey, can you copy paste your code directly from Xcode? Your errors aren't corresponding to the ones showing up when I copy-paste your code. In addition, try fixing these: `@Environment(\.isEnabled)` (add the backslash), `.buttonStyle(SmallButtonStyle())` (add the two `()`), and one of your `.buttonStyle` modifiers has nothing inside it. It's the one beneath `configuration.label`. So add `SmallButtonStyle()` inside of it. If none of this resolves your issue please copy-paste directly from Xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these changes your code compiles and works:

- when setting the button style, you need to create an actual instance of `SmallButtonStyle`
- inside `makeBody`, don't use the modifier `.buttonStyle` (which would need to be supplied with a style as parameter)
- add a backslash to escape the name of the environment value
- I had to change the purple to the standard purple in order to test the code.

So this works:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ButtonStyleGuide: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing:30) {
            Text("Button Styles")

            Button { } label: {
                Text("small primary button style")
            }
            .buttonStyle(SmallButtonStyle())

            Button { } label: {
                Text("small primary button - disabled")
            }
            .buttonStyle(SmallButtonStyle())
            .disabled(true)
        }
    }
}

struct SmallButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    @Environment(\.isEnabled) var isEnabled

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
//            .buttonStyle()
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .background(Capsule().fill(.purple)) // Color("purple-500")
            .padding(12.5)
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.8 : 1)
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]